# jQuery addClass stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason jQuery.addClass has stoped working. I have no idea why.
Other stuff works though.

```
  // Change row background color on click
  jQuery('#rowList tr').live("click", function() {
    alert(jQuery(this).attr('title')); // Just here for testing. This works
    alert(jQuery(this).css('border','solid 1px red')); // Just here for testing. This works

    jQuery(this).closest("tr").siblings().removeClass("selected"); 
    jQuery(this).addClass("selected");  // NOT working
  });
```

Any reason why this is not working? Here is my HTML:

```
<table id="rowList">
  <tbody>
    <tr title="My title 1" class="imageItem odd"> <td>some stuff</td></tr>
    <tr title="My title 2" class="imageItem even"><td> some stuff here</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Were you trying to add `class="selected"` to the `tr` or the `td`?

Comment: I'm adding the class to the `tr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a missing `)` on the second alert:

```
alert(jQuery(this).css('border','solid 1px red'));
                                               ^
```

Once you fix that it works, [you can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/eNE6L/).  As an aside, since you're on a `<tr>`, there's no need for the `.closest("tr")` call, you can remove it from the chain, something like this overall:

CSS:

```
.bordered { border: solid 1px red; }
```

Script:

```
jQuery('#rowList tr').live("click", function() {
  alert(jQuery(this).attr('title'));
  jQuery(this).addClass("bordered selected")
              .siblings().removeClass("selected"); 
});​
```

[You can give it a go here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/PQwd7/).

Comment: The alerts are just for testing - and just a typo from me. It's the addClass that is not working. This has been working all along up til now.

Comment: @Steven - It works in my demo...pretty simple behavior here, is it possible your CSS is something like `td.className` and not `tr.className`?

Comment: I removed the two lines with jQuery to add / remove the class, and then it worked.... so there must be something else bugging up my sytem. But thanks for the short code - less overhead.

Comment: BTW. Nice sand box that link of yours.

Answer (score 0):

Because the way you've written it is the `.addClass()` adds the class to the `td` not the parent `tr`.

Unless the omission of `closest('tr')` was a typo?